# Subwoofer Logitech Z333 not working

Tags: linux, audio, fedora

I got a new Logitech Z333 and the left/right speakers work fine. However, there is no sound coming out of the subwoofer at all. Its volume is turned to max, so that's not it.

Running `pavucontrol` shows in the section `Output Devices` that I have left speaker, right speaker, and a subwoofer all set at 100% volume. The `Playback` section shows volume only for the left and right speakers which might be part of the problem.

[ALSA info](http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=c382f43b07158b18752d259a7a3512218c28c490), in case that helps.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your Linux subwoofer port mapped to the right output of your soundcard?

Comment: @BigChris: No idea. How would I find out?

Comment: How is it connected to your computer? The specs I google say it only has a stereo analog input, so I suppose it computes the subwoofer channel internally (which probably must be enabled). Do you have a link to a manual?

Comment: @dirkt subwoofer was dead. That was the problem. 